# Protecting myself in Ukraine

Tags: internet, international

I am a United States citizen planning a week-long trip to Ukraine. A friend advised me that Internet security is less-than-great there. What steps should I take to protect myself if I use public or hotel wifi connections for my smart phone and laptop while there?  Anything different than I would do in the US?  (which right now is limited to common sense and not sending important information on non-HTTPS sites)

Comment: Check out how VPN services work. Choose an approriate app.

Comment: We are asking the same questions here in Germany if a trip to the US is planned... ;)

Answer (score 5):

As ott mentioned & let me reinforce it: Use a VPN! Especially for email sign in and banking. It's best to use it for any login activities. A traveller named Nomadic Matt wrote a couple of good articles to help you pick out which is the best for you:

[Everything You Need To Know About VPNs for Travel](http://www.nomadicmatt.com/travel-blogs/set-up-vpn-travel/) (HINT: if you are traveling with a phone and a laptop, choose a provider that supports multiple devices)

[The No-Nonsense Guide to Data Security for Travelers](http://www.nomadicmatt.com/travel-blogs/data-security-for-travelers/)

Other things to do:

- I personally bring a couple of small new storage USB drives (>4GB) as throw aways in case I have to print from at an internet cafe. In foreign countries, these computers can be riddled with viruses.
- Have a PIN code on your mobile devices. If it supports swipe, it has been shown that grease prints make it fairly easy to re-create your pattern. Also turn on feature to wipe after a limited number of incorrect attempts.
- Make sure you are using encryption on your phone (SD card included) and full-disk encryption for your computer. Have these devices turned off when entering the country and passing through customs (beware that you may be asked to turn on and decrypt).
- Consider limiting the data that you take to the country. If you don't need it, leave it at home with your back-ups.
- Phone theft (esp. these nice shiny expensive smartphones we have) can be common depending on the areas you are visiting. Have a remote wiping application enabled on your phone. I wouldn't put too much hope in the tracking feature as some countries do not have resources to "track down the phone of a tourist" they might have bigger fish to fry.
- Get the correct plug adapter ([whatplug.info](http://whatplug.info/from/uk/to/ukraine) shows G,D & M)) and do not charge from USB stations like you may do in American airports.
- Turn on two factor authentication methods for email and banking during your trip. You could have these warnings forwarded to a service like Google Voice (free).
- Keep Wi-Fi and cell service off (airplane mode) when not using it to avoid connections.

A more thorough checklist is provided here by and article in [Security Magazine](http://www.securitymagazine.com/articles/85271-checklist-24-steps-for-data-security-while-traveling-abroad). This list may seem like overkill but depending on your job and the type of data you carry (read: the stakeholders of that data) they may be more essential.

Have a great trip!